# How to Sort based on embedded Property and limit the no of results with Specifications?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to understand and figure out the solution for the following use case

These are my entity classes

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User  {
  private UserID id;
  private Set<UserAddress> addresses = new HashSet<UserAddress>(0);
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 32)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userType", column = @Column(name = "USER_TYPE", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)) })
  public User getId() {
     return this.id;
  }
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  mappedBy = "user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})    
  @BatchSize(size=50)
  public Set<UserAddress> getAddresses() {
    return this.addresses;
  }
  ........
}
```

UserAddress

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERADDRESS")
public class UserAddress  {
  private UserID id;
  Private User user;
  private String address; 
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 32)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "userType", column = @Column(name = "USER_TYPE", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 0)) })
  public User getId() {
     return this.id;
  }
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "userType", referencedColumnName = "USER_TYPE", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false) })
  public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }
  ........
}
```

UserId

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {
   private String userNo;
   private Long UserType;
   .......
   .......
}
```

I have created a staticmetamodel class for User, UserID and UserAddress and created query based on Specifications.

Metamodel class for User

```
@StaticMetamodel(User.class)
public abstract class User_ {

  public static volatile SetAttribute<User, UserAddress> addresses;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, UserID> id;
}
```

Metamodel for UserId

```
@StaticMetamodel(UserID.class)
public abstract class UserID_ {
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserID, String> userNo;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserID, Long> UserType;
}
```

**I am trying to retrieve maximum of 10 User objects ordered by UserType and searched based on userId. The query has to retrieve the UserAddresses as an eager fetch.**

My Specification Object is

UserSpecification

```
public class UserSpecifications {
   public static Specification<User> userNoIs(String userNo) {
      return (root, query, cb) -> {
        root.fetch(User_.addresses);
        return cb.equal(root.get(User_.id).get(UserID_.userNo),userNo);
      };
   }
}
```

DAO Function:

```
 Sort sortInstructions = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id.userNo");
 Specifications<User> specifications = Specifications.where(userNoIs(input.getUserNo()));
 List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll(specifications,sortInstructions);
```

I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl$Identifier cannot be cast to javax.persistence.metamodel.ManagedType
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateManagedType(AbstractFromImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:194)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:287)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:261)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:441)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:294)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:322)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `root.fetch(User_.userAddresses);` - in you `User` class you have `addresses` not `userAddresses` so probably you wrongly generated metamodel for that.

Another thing that addresses should be `ListAttribute` not `SingularAttribute`.

UPDATE EDIT:
Try to use newer version, problem you described was solved in spring-data 1.5

Comment: I have added my metamodel to the question. I am using a SetAttribute and corrected the fetch function mistake. Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you try without sorting mechanism and tell if problem also occurs? For now I don't know if problem comes from sorting or from specification

Comment: I have tried without sorting and it is working correctly. Only when I introduce Sorting or pagination, I am getting the exceptions. Even in this case Sorting works if I give it on the embedded id instead of property inside embedded id.    Sort sortInstructions = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");   --> This works. But ideally it should be with a property inside an ID.

Comment: Which version of spring data are you using?

Comment: I am using  spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.M1.jar  , hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar, hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar , hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

Comment: Can you try with newer version of spring-data-jpa? I found similar issue to yours here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-497 and there is a merged pull request but valid for newer version. This version you are using is from 2011.

Comment: Also I realized that I used similar sorting by property of key and it is working in newer version.

Comment: I updated spring-data-jpa to new veresion 1.6.2.RELEASE and it worked smoothly as you said. Thanks for helping out. I am still facing issue on Pageable fetch though. Trying to hash it out.